# How to check if char* p reached end of a C string?

Tags: c++

```
template<class IntType>
IntType atoi_unsafe(const char* source)
{
    IntType result = IntType();
    while (source)
    {
        auto t = *source;
        result *= 10;
        result += (*source - 48);
        ++source;
    }
    return result;
}
```

and in `main()` I have:

```
char* number = "14256";
atoi_unsafe<unsigned>(number);
```

but the condition `while (source)` does not seem to recognize that `source` has iterated over the entire C string. How should it correctly check for the end of the string?

Comment: `while(*source)`

Comment: @ughoavgfhw and world makes sense again! +1

Comment: ughoavgfhw, You should put that as an answer so that smallB can accept it

Comment: @ughoavgfhw: Post that as an answer!

Comment: Answer and acceptance in comment form. ARGH!

Comment: BTW, LOL at the irony of writing a function named `atoi_unsafe`.

Comment: I'd also suggest using `'0'` instead of `48`, it'll result in the same machine code, but the intent is much more obvious.

Comment: @Ben I somewhat disagree with you on this one. Subtracting 48 is clear indication that we converting from something to something (char to int here) on the other hand subtracting '0' from '1' for example isn't at all intuitional. But that's how I see it.

Comment: @smallB: What's the purpose of `t`?

Comment: @Ben that's was the "tmp" variable which I've used to check what is the value of *source after end of the cstring. Removed in release ver of course.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`while(source)` is true until the pointer wraps around to 0, but will probably crash well before that in modern systems. You need to dereference the pointer to find a null byte, `while(*source)`.

<sub><sub>I hate posting short answers</sub></sub>

Comment: You may hate it, but if it solves problems, earn the rep for good eyes. :P

Answer (score 12):

The pointer does not go to zero at the end of the string; the end of the string is found when the value pointed at becomes zero.  Hence:

```
while (*source != '\0')
```

You might, more compactly, write the whole function as:

```
template<class IntType>
IntType atoi_unsafe(const char* source)
{
    IntType result = IntType();
    char c;
    while ((c = *source++) != '\0')
        result = result * 10 + (c - '0');
    return result;
}
```

Granted, it does not use the `auto` keyword.  Also note carefully the difference between `'\0'` and `'0'`.  The parentheses in the assignment in the loop body are not necessary.

Your code only handles strings without a sign - and should arguably validate that the characters are actually digits too (maybe raising an exception if the input is invalid).  The 'unsafe' appellation certainly applies.  Note, too, that if you instantiate the template for a signed integer type and the value overflows, you invoke undefined behaviour.  At least with unsigned types, the arithmetic is defined, even if probably not what is expected.

Comment: Q, do you need  test for this: (c = *source++) != '\0', isn't c = *source++) enough?

Comment: @smallB: it depends on your compiler options.  Mine compiles clean with warnings set excruciating; the alternative gets `warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]` from GCC (G++) 4.6.  This is with `-Wall -Wextra` compilation options.  The extra condition affirms that the assignment is intentional, not a typo for `c == *source++`.

Comment: fair enough, but in my code I'll go for the "really brutal" ver. Thanks again. Great code!

Answer (score 3):

You need to look for the null-terminator at the end of the string.  Waiting for the pointer to wrap around to `0` is probably never going to happen.  Use `while (*source)` for your loop.